# Spring.Net ref to Dictionary item

Tags: c#, dictionary, spring.net

I can't find out how use an item defined in dictionary (xml spring config) at other place in the spring xml file. I tried something like this, but I ever get an error in init of "obj1".

```
  <object name="Paths" id="Paths" type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string,string&gt;">
    <constructor-arg>
      <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="string">
        <entry key="cfgFile">
          <value>config.txt</value>
        </entry>
      </dictionary>
    </constructor-arg>
  </object>  
  <object name="obj1" type="MyTestClass" depends-on="Paths">
    <property name="cfg" expression="${Paths['cfgFile']}"/>
  </object>
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Could you post the details of you error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer was accepted, but now I believe a better answer would be:

Your expression is not correct, it should be:

```xmk
<object name="obj1" type="MyTestClass" depends-on="Paths">
  <property name="cfg" expression="@(Paths)['cfgFile']"/>
</object>
```

You can use the `@(object-id-here)` [expression syntax to retrieve an object from the Spring context using an expression](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-object-references).

**Edit - below is the answer that was accepted**

I can imagine that you would like this kind of configuration to be available in your `app.config`. If so, you can use the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`; see the example in [section 5.9.2.1](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-placeholderconfigurer).

In your case, it would look something like this:

```xml
<!-- app.config -->
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="PathConfiguration" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
  </configSections>

  <PathConfiguration>
    <add key="cfgFile" value="config.txt"/>
    <add key="otherCfgFile" value="otherconfig.txt"/>
  </PathConfiguration>

  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="mycongfig.xml"/>
    </context>
  </spring>

</configuration>
```

And your `myconfig.xml` contains:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<object name="obj1" type="MyTestClass">
    <property name="cfg" value="${cfgFile}"/>
</object>

<object name="appConfigPropertyHolder" 
        type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">

    <property name="configSections">          
      <value>PathConfiguration</value>                              
    </property>              

</object>
<!-- ... -->
```

Note that instead of `app.config`, you can use any other `IResource`.

An alternative solution is to define the `cfgFile` as an object in your configuration and then in your dictionary reference this object using `value-ref` (see spring docs [5.3.2.4](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-collections-values) on how to do this). But this (probably) isn't what you are looking for, since you're injecting primitive values (so it's not worth the effort of creating an explicit `ConfigurationObject`).

Comment: That is what I looked for, both approaches are valuable for my purposes.